# How to save int values in a while loop?

Tags: c++

My question is this, how do I save an int value in a while loop, my code is all about gambling, you start with 1,000 and you want to make the most amount of cash, but when I roll again my cash restores back to its original value that I set.

My code is this (Note I am new so do not laugh at how bad it is)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char again = 'Y';
    int test;
    int yes;
    int CashW;
    CashW = 1000;
    int CashL;
    CashL = 1000;
    int yLose;
    yLose = 500;
    int xCash;
    xCash = 1000;
    int xRan;
    srand(time(0));
    xRan = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << " Welcome to the Gambling Game!" << endl;
        cout << " If the number is above 50 I win!" << endl;
        cout << " If the number is below 50 you lose!" << endl;
        while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
        {
        cout << " The Number I Choose Is: " << xRan << endl;


        CashL = xCash - xCash - xCash;
        CashW = xCash + xCash;


        if (xRan < 50) {
            cout << " You win, rats!" << endl;
            cout << " The cash you started with was: " << xCash << endl;
            cout << " The cash you have now is: " << CashW << endl;
            cout << " Type 1 to play again, type 2 to close the game." << endl;
            cin >> yes;

        }

        if (xRan > 50) {
            cout << " I win, you lose!" << endl;
            cout << " The cash you started with was: " << xCash << endl;
            cout << " The cash you have now is: " << CashL << endl;
            cout << " Type 1 to play again, type 2 to close the game." << endl;
            cin >> yes;

        }

        if (yes == 1) {
            cout << " Cool, a gambling man! Time to make some cash" << endl;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You should only use one variable to store the current cash for the player. Increase it or decrease it in the if statements for winning or loosing. You have to move the random number generation inside the while loop to get different results at every turn.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you currently display either `CashW` or `CashL` depending on the gampbling result.

Unfortunately, you only print out the result and never store it into  `xCash`.  So at next iteration you start again with the same `xCash` value !

You can easily solve this by adding `xCash = CashW;` or `xCash = CashL;` just under the line in which you display the result.

Comment: That should probably be `xCash += CashW` and `xCash -= CashL` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau in fact I hesitated.  The text displayed by OP is:  *"The cash you have now is ..."*. So I assumed it was indeed the total and not incremental wins.  But thanks for the comments:  it will help OP to adjust in case I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

You are never updating `xCash` with the amount of each win/loss.  You are not generating a new random number on each loop iteration.  And you are stuck in an endless loop because you never update the loop variable `again`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int CashW = 1000;
    const int CashL = 1000;

    int xCash = 1000;
    int xRan;
    char answer;

    srand(time(0));

    cout << " Welcome to the Gambling Game!" << endl;
    cout << " If the number is above 50 I win!" << endl;
    cout << " If the number is below 50 you win!" << endl;

    do
    {
        xRan = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << " The Number I Choose Is: " << xRan << endl;

        if (xRan < 50) {
            cout << " You win, rats!" << endl;
            cout << " The cash you started with was: " << xCash << endl;
            xCash += CashW;
            cout << " The cash you have now is: " << xCash << endl;
        }

        else if (xRan > 50) {
            cout << " I win, you lose!" << endl;
            cout << " The cash you started with was: " << xCash << endl;
            xCash -= CashL;
            cout << " The cash you have now is: " << xCash << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << " dang, a draw!" << endl;
        }

        cout << " play again? " << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if ((answer != 'y') && (answer != 'Y')) {
            cout << " All done? Come back again another time!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << " Cool, a gambling man! Time to make some cash" << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```